# In PrimeFaces use selected elements to display in p:dataTable from DataModel

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, datamodel

I am displaying data in a `<p:dataTable>` where the values are coming from `DataModel`. Code is:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{studentSummaryBean.studentModel}" var="student"....>
 .....
</p:dataTable>
```

The `DataModel` is implemented as below:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class StudentDataModel extends LazyDataModelHelper<Student> implements Serializable {
.....
}
```

This is working perfectly fine and showing all students available.
Now I have a list which is basically a subset of all available students (subset means it can contain all students, no student or few students). List is:

```
private List<Student> selectedStudents;
```

Now my requirement is that in the data table I should display only those students who are there in the `selectedStudents` list. I **have to** use `StudentDataModel` only to display in datatable as the `StudentDataModel` is having other properties calculated which are not there in the `selectedStudents` list. Any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Not sure what you're concretely asking, but the `StudentDateModel` being a managed bean is quite strange. It isn't supposed to be a managed bean by itself, but just a property of a true managed bean like as the `StudentSummaryBean` as you already have.

Comment: I was think of passing selectedStudents list to the predicates to fetch only common Students between selectedStudents and StudentDataModel. Let me see if I can do that. But before that one question why do you think StudentDataModel should not be a managed bean? May be you can educate me why we should not have a datamodel as managed bean?